# WCF Service runs perfectly when running under iis express but same service wont work when running under Local IIS with its virtual directory

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, iis-express

I was practising WCF and stuck to this situation.
My Wcf service works perfectly under IISExpress (default for VS2013).
But When I use the same under Local IIS, I got below exception in WCF Test Client.

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error URI: http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc Metadata contains
>   a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc'. The remote server
>   returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed. The remote
>   server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.HTTP GET Error URI:
>   http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc There was an error
>   downloading 'http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc'. The request
>   failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

My web config has endpoint for metadata exchange and also behaviour has httpGetEnabled true.

See web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="f:\tfs\wcfservice1\wcfservice1\web_messages.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="behave" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="WcfService1.Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttp"
          contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WcfService1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behave">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I checked other WCF questions. but couldn't find answer. 
Thanks in advance.

When I use Local IIS, I am able to hit url 
http://localhost/wcfservice1/
and it shows me all files at that directory.
but when I click on Service1.svc, it shows IIS error page.

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be
>   served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME
>   map.

After addng WCF activation in IIS. Now I am getting different Error.
I couldn't understand it.
[image]

Comment: If you go to the site in IIS Manager, can you right-click and browse to it? Is your IIS site running and  configured for port 80?

Comment: I would look into http vs https bindings. It seems you only expose https but the meta data might only be available for http.

Comment: I have updated my question with required details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable WCF in IIS Manager for your site, see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/blambert/2009/02/13/how-to-enable-iis7asp-net-and-wcf-http-activation/

Once WCF is enabled for IIS you should be able to run everything without a problem.

Comment: Hi, I have changes as you suggested. and now I am getting another error. I posted picture in my question.

Comment: Have you recycled IIS, stop and then start it back up again since you made the changes, then try accessing the site?

Comment: Yes ..  tried.. I am getting same error..I have attached picture in question.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved issue. 
I have turned on  .Net framework 4.6 advanced services > WCF services > HTTP activation.
Now WCF service is working perfectly.

Thanx to gmiley.. your previous answer led me there.